# Glare node is visible in the viewer node but not in the render result

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, viewlayers, glare

So my glare node is not working properly. I am working on an animation and in the composite tab the glare node is visible but not in the render result.

[image: See the image maybe it will help you]

[image: the render result]

Comment: can u pls show us your render result?

Comment: Is it not showing after rendering with the _Glare_ node already applied in the _Compositor_ or does the render in the _Image Editor_ not show the glare directly after adding the node in the _Compositor_? If the latter, make sure in the _Image Editor_ you have enabled _View_ > _Update Automatically_. But still, the _Image Editor_ sometimes doesn't refresh. For single images you could also switch the image from _Render Result_ to _Viewer Node_, it updates immediately and you could also save from there. Anyway, rendering an animation with automatic saving should show the glare in the saved files.

Comment: i saw and i have enabled the update automatically in the image editor.....i mean at starting with few projects the glare worked fine but after some projects the glare doesnt work properly anymore

Comment: ok i will share my render result